# Override the automatic generated view_name in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a Restful API with Django REST Framework. What I have is a project with two different apps. One app is called `project/catalog` and one is called `project/environment`. Both of the apps have a model called `Device` and their own `url.py` file, which will be included in the `project/url.py` file.

The urls from the apps are included with a namespace in `project/url.py`:

```
# project/url.py

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'api/', include(('environment.urls', 'environment'))),
    path(r'api/', include(('catalog.urls', 'catalog')))
]
```

The `basename` for the urls are automatic generated because in the `viewSet` I have a attribute `queryset`

**My question is:**
Is it possible to override the automatic `view_name` generation to use the pattern with a namespace? What it says in the documentation is that the `view_name` is generated like this `(model_name)-detail` for example. What I want is that the `view_name` will be generated like this `(app_name):(model_name)-detail`

I can use the namespace when I create the `HyperlinkedIdentityField` by my self and add the `view_name` attribute, like below:

```
# project/catalog/serializer.py

class DeviceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='catalog:device-detail')
        class Meta:
            model = models.Device
            fields = [
                'url',
                 ...
```

```
# project/environment/serializer.py

class DeviceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='environment:device-detail')
        class Meta:
            model = models.Device
            fields = [
                'url',
                 ...
```

But once I remove the example above it throws the `Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "device-detail"` exception. Because the automatic generated `view_name` excpects `device-detail`, but I want it to expect `catalog:device-detail` for the catalog app or `environment:device-detail` for the environment app.

**Some solutions I know about are:**

- Removing the namespace in `project/url.py`, but then there are two apps urls which has the same basename. In `project/catalog` the basename will be `device-detail` as same for `project/environment`. This will give issues because it will only look at one basename.
- Change the `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` to just `ModelSerializer`, but that doesn't really fix my problem for my use case
- Define every `HyperlinkedIdentityField` and add the `view_name` for every serializer, but that will be a pain for maintenance

**My app url files**

```
# project/catalog/url.py

from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from catalog import views

router.register(r'devices', views.DeviceViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('catalog/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

```
# project/environment/url.py

from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from environment import views

router.register(r'devices', views.DeviceViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('environment/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

---

### EDIT

I have for example the `AssemblySerializer` in the app environment `project/environment/serializer.py`. Because I have two apps which can have the same urls I have to use namespaces, which is OK and what I want.

```
class AssemblySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Assembly
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'view_name': 'environment:installedassembly-detail'},
            'device': {'view_name': 'environment:device-detail'},
            'parent': {'view_name': 'environment:installedassembly-detail'},
            'catalog_assembly': {'view_name': 'catalog:assembly-detail'}
        }
```

What I don't want is to set for each serializer the `view_name` like in the example above. I want that it will automatic look at the namespace of the app environment so that I only have to define a view_name when its outside the app, like the example below.

```
class AssemblySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Assembly
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'catalog_assembly': {'view_name': 'catalog:assembly-detail'}
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use namespaces in this case.

If you are using recent Django then you should specify an app namespace in your `urls.py` using `app_name="catalog"`.  You can override this in `include()` if needed.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'api/environment/', include('environment.urls')),
    path(r'api/catalog/', include('catalog.urls')),
]
```

Your urls.py can then be simplified like this:

```
app_name = 'catalog'
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

And you can reverse the lookup using that namespace (they can also be nested).  Read up on setting the `view_name` on [HyperlinkedModelSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#how-hyperlinked-views-are-determined):

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['account_url', 'account_name', 'users', 'created']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'view_name': 'accounts', 'lookup_field': 'account_name'},
            'users': {'lookup_field': 'username'}
        }
```

If you need to add custom urls outside the router, then just add them as normal.

```
urlpatterns += [
    path('other/', some_view_func, )
    path('ship/', include(("other_thing.urls", "ship"))
]
```

I highly recommend you install [`django_extensions`](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/In) installed so you can view your routes:

```
$> ./manage.py show_urls | column -t
...
PATH                    VIEW FUNC         VIEW NAME
/catalog/items/         app.ItemViewSet   catalog:item-list
/catalog/items/<pk>/    app.ItemViewSet   catalog:item-detail
...
```

The `include` function is a little strange, I'll give you that.  I have [a helper that I use](https://gist.github.com/awbacker/4b78b91a423177bcc1db4ec3e12e25fa) which makes it consistent, and usually removes the need for routers:

```
urlpatterns = [
    route('layouts/', LayoutViewSet, name="layouts"),
    route('admin/', admin_urls, name='admin'),
    route('catalog/', 'apps.catalog.urls', name='catalog'),
    etc
]
```

Comment: This is indeed a good solution and sort of answer my question, but I think I have not stated very clearly what I want. I don't want to specify the `view_name` for each `url` in the serializer, but I want that the namespace is used automatic without adding `extra_kwargs`. For now I have added your solution and it works, but it is not entirely what I want. I hope you recognize my problem.

Comment: You have to specify the view name.  You have 2 views, both of which would otherwise have the same "default" name and clash, and with a more complex api you want namespaces.  You can also specify the view name on the serializer field directly, `HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="env:device", ...)` as covered in the next section of the linked documentation.  Does that work?

Comment: I understand that you have to specify the `view_name` because I have two different apps with the same Model names. The namespacing works and everthing you said works, but I wondered if it was possible to define the namespace in a variable for each app so you don't have to keep adding a `view_name`. I will edit my question so I can give a better example of what I mean